# Any lib for multi-threading cross-platform for Delphi AND FreePascal?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, cross-platform, freepascal

I'm aware of some Windows Thread Libs for Delphi(OmniThread Lib, BMThreads, etc).

But is there a lib that is built to be cross-platform and that can both be used under Delphi and FreePascal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although these are not links to threading libraries per se, the information on the following pages might (or might not) be of use when researching threading on Windows/Linux and MACOSX

1. [Multithreading with Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial).
2. OSX Multithreading forum...[thread](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/forum/index.php?topic=5310.0).

Sorry couldn't offer anything more specific.

Comment: I've read both of those and they only talk about TThread. That's too simple from were I stand.

Answer (score 2):

Both FPC/Lazarus and Delphi support TThread. FPC doesn't suppport TMREWS though (it does have the identifier but it is a simple lock).

But I assume you mean some thread pooling classes? What do you exactly need, and why is the Delphi built in support not enough?

Comment: This is a question to help me on the Dweetta project. I'm already wrapping sock libs(synapse and indy soon) and wanted to do the same for Threads. And because I love OmniThread Lib I thought that someone had already made on for FPC. Look like I'll have to swing it and have different stuff for each, or just use the default TTHread.

Comment: Delphi/FPC have their own thread abstraction, so the need for extra libs is relatively unneeded.